# Is there a way to read nested array and extract only one value from the nested array using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I need to read the json file from my storage account and get only id from the json array of objects and extract only the id from the array.

I tried to use lookup activity to get the array of json objects and used that output to a for each activity by providing `@array(activity('Lookup').output.value[0].lists)`

Below json script is the output of the lookup activity

````
"count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "obj": 123,
            "lists": {
                "employees": [
                    {
                        "name": "",
                        "id": "001",
                        "tt_1": 0,
                        "tt_2": 4,
                        "tt3_": 1
},
{
                        "name": "",
                        "id": "002",
                        "tt_1": 10,
                        "tt_2": 8,
                        "tt3_": 1
}```

Need some way to loop through the array of objects and extract only the id and save it in a separate file.
I tried to narrow down till employees using set variables array type but unable to loop through array of objects and extract the id 

Please help me to find out some solution to extract the id from the array? Please suggest if sqldb or any other way to extract id?
````

Comment: Hi @dfbeg, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Data Flow [Flatten active](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten) to flatten the json array `value.list.employees` to get the ID value, then import the id to a csv file.

I just create a piece of same JSON data with you, please ref the example bellow.

```
{   
    "count": 1,
    "value": [{
                "obj": 123,
                "lists": [{
                            "employees": [{
                                
                                    "name": "",
                                    "id": "001",
                                    "tt_1": 0,
                                    "tt_2": 4,
                                    "tt3_": 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "",
                                    "id": "002",
                                    "tt_1": 10,
                                    "tt_2": 8,
                                    "tt3_": 1
                                }]
                        }]
                }]                  
}
```

**Source data and schema:**
[image]

**Flatten active settings and output preview:**
[image]

[image]

Then we could copy the ID data to SQL DB or a csv file.

HTH.